# populate dropdown only when its clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 6 dropdowns in a aspx page. I need to populate the dropdown only when its clicked. 
Initially I populated all 6 ddl in page load but there was a huge delay in loading the page so I got this option to populate the ddl only when its clicked. I couldn't find the right answer yet, tried with diff sol and query.

And i couldn't find any 'Onclick','Onmousedown','Onkeypress' in ddl.
I even tried one option shared in stackoverflow by an user.

pls find the below code and help to solve the issue.

```
 <td class="style10" >
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGM"   Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True" onclick="javascript:clickHiddenButton();" onselectedindexchanged="ddlGM_SelectedIndexChanged" style="height: 22px" >
  <asp:ListItem Value=0 Text="All"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList><div style="display: none;">
  <asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                    </div></td>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickHiddenButton() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnHidden');
    var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlGM');
    if (ddl.length == 1) {
        btn.click();
    }
}
</script>
```

---

```
 protected void btnHidden_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dvfilters = (DataView)(Cache["FiltersData"]);
    dtt = dvfilters.ToTable();
    ddlGM.DataSource = dtt;
    ddlGM.DataValueField = "GlobalMarket";

    ddlGM.DataBind();
    RemoveDuplicateItems(ddlGM);
    SortDDL(ref ddlGM);
    //ddlGM.Items.Insert(0, "All");
}
```

Comment: You should not do post back to load ddl when you click on it. You should have some JavaScript code which will be executed when you click on ddl  and call server method via Ajax. Server method should return only data ( no html) and JavaScript code should use that data to create items in the ddl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .focus function for any element. focus function is called when the particular function get clicked or getting focus by anyway. I am putting sample code for you. You can change this code as your need.

```
<script>
    var bDataLoded = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ddVal = '';
        $('#ddlGM').focus(function () {
            if (!bDataLoded) {
                alert("hi");
                $('#ddlGM').append('<option value=' + 1 + '> + Test 1 + </option>');
                $('#ddlGM').append('<option value=' + 2 + '> + Test 2 + </option>');
                $('#ddlGM').append('<option value=' + 3 + '> + Test 3 + </option>');
                $('#ddlGM').append('<option value=' + 4 + '> + Test 4 + </option>');
                bDataLoded = true;
            }
            $('#ddlGM').blur();
        })
    });

</script>
```

---

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGM"   Width="150px" AutoPostBack="True" style="height: 22px" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
```

---

Hope this will solve your problem.